# Grammatical Nuisance: The particle "in order" to in Korean ? [기 위해; 러 and 려고]

Tags: grammar, meaning, particle

What different nuisance is conveyed in the following forms:

> 공부하**기 위해** 학교에 가고 있다
>
> 공부하**러** 학교에 가고 있다
>
> 공부하**려고** 학교에 가고 있다

The translations for both are: *I’m going to school to study*

**But is there any meaning difference embedded in the forms ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning is more or less the same since they all indicate the purpose.

The difference is in formality and usage context.

- VERB-기 위해 = in order to VERB.  Most formal, so mostly used in writing.
- VERB-러 = to VERB.  Only used with movement verbs like come, go, or attend.
- VERB-려고 = to VERB.  General, all-around phrase for "to VERB" or "wanting to VERB".

So sentences like 좋은 학교에 들어가러 열심히 공부했다 sounds a little strange.  It should be  들어가려고 (or 들어가기 위해서 more formally).